# Android restore animation on activity resume

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I have an activity where i do a scale animation on a view when a button is clicked.
I have set fillAfter as true for the animation.
When the animation is done, I start another activity. The problem is when I go back to my original activity, my scaled view is back to its original size.

Is there anyway to leave the activities content view the way it is when we start another activity?

I read the saveInstanceState, but most posts over here refer to saving values and not the UI. Im not really sure how to tackle this issue in a efficient way.

Or should I save the scaled view and restore it on the onResume function of the activity?

Comment: After further inspection, i think my Tabactivity is causing the problem. Normally the activity should look the same way we leave it but i think my implementation of tabactivity is causing the problem. So now looking for a way to properly implement tabs in android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by adding the launchMode attribute in the manifest file.

Comment: I just added this to the acitivity tag in the manifest file android:launchMode="singleTask"